# How can i put white-space in combo box in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

[image]

In this attached image the text of the list is too long and it is not fully coming how can i break that?

{ClassScheduleError}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a label in your option in the combo box. Then the whole text will be seen.
Hope it helps.
It will look like the below image.
[image]

Comment: Label is already added but there is no any option so that i can break that text?